# how can is prevnet script injection in ckeditor for asp.net 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-injection

I use the ckeditor control in my page, for inserting data to my database, this control allowing malicious users to  inject scripts to my database.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Here is the code used to insert into the database.

`CKeditor1.text` contains the text from the editor control.

```
intro = intro + "....";
myStatic.insertFields("ID,Title, Block,isDep,dat,imgpath,intro", " E_News", "" + maxID + ",'" + txtTitle.Text + "','" + CKEditor1.Text.Trim() + "'," + isDep + ",'" + d + "','" + txtimgpath.Text + "','" +intro.Trim()+"'");
```

Comment: What code are you using? Sounds like you need some input sanitisation.

Comment: i use c# language for inserting data.I need prevent ckeditor from inserting script like <script> alter(1); </script> .. or other script example

Comment: What code does the ckeditor use to insert into the database? That is where you need to do your sanitisation. You really need to include these details in your question.

Comment: intro = intro + "....";
                myStatic.insertFields("ID,Title, Block,isDep,dat,imgpath,intro", " E_News", "" + maxID + ",'" + txtTitle.Text
                    + "','" + CKEditor1.Text.Trim() + "'," + isDep + ",'" + d + "','" + txtimgpath.Text + "','" +intro.Trim()+"'");

Comment: CKeditor1.text : contains the Ckeditor value

Comment: give me an example . how can i used it

Comment: Like Maysam said, use SQL parameters, because it looks like you may be open for SQL injection attacks too. Use google if you need examples - there are plenty of them.

Comment: private bool TestCkeditorValue(string str)
    {
        string[] strarray = str.Split(new string[] { "<script>", "</script>" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        if (strarray.Length > 1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }...... i used this code . and worked fine if false dose not allowed me to insert data otherwise insert data to database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution would be to encode the values entered into the database. This of course depends on how the values stored are then output once again.

Another option would be to have a black list of characters that could be considered dangerous, and then just reject the input all together.

.NET has some functionality built in to reject requests that contain potentially dangerous input, but I dont know enough about your situation..

HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode would be suitable for encoding the script for storage in your database. However if you decode it when you output it, you will have the same problem!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz.aspx

Therefore you should use a whitelist and reject any input containing script tags (You should find a library to do this for you)

As Maysam mentions you also need to use SQL parameters to ensure that users cannot perform SQL injection attacks on your database, there are plenty of guides around on how to do this.

**Edit:**

This will do what you want, but I would recommend you use a library for this sort of thing.

```
if (str.IndexOf("<script>", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) > -1)
            return true;
```

Information about the MS Anti XSS Library: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973813.aspx

Comment: can help me to build i whilelist for reject <script> tag from ckeditor.text value string . please

Comment: private bool TestCkeditorValue(string str)
    {
        string[] strarray = str.Split('>');
        foreach (String strvalue in strarray)
        {
            if (String.Compare(strvalue, "<script>", false) == 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    } ..............this is my code but that wrong .. beacuse the split function will not work . i need the way to  spilte tags and test each one individually

Comment: I have updated my answer. Take a look at the guide on how to format things, it would make your posts much easier to read when code is involved - http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help